# Bugzilla REST Interface - How to provide API Key and authenticate for a POST request

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

I am able to make a [GET Request](http://ashish-sureka-delhi.blogspot.in/2016/09/invoking-bugzilla-rest-interface-from.html) (please click on the link to see the program I have written to make a GET Request) to Bugzilla REST API as it does not require a username/password for authentication. However, creating a bug (POST Request) requires a username and password. I generated the API key also but not able to find documentation on how to use the API Key from within a PHP program to make a REST POST call to a Bugzilla Server. When I execute the following program, I get an error: You must log in before using this part of Bugzilla.,code:410. Any help in resolving the issue is appreciated

```
       $url ="http://localhost:8080/bugzilla/rest/bug";
       $apikey = "IZC4rs2gstCal0jEZosFjDBRV9AQv2gF0udh4hgq";
       $data = array(
            "product" => "TestProduct",
            "component" => "TestComponent",
            "version" => "unspecified",
            "summary" => "This is a test bug - please disregard",
            "alias" => "SomeAlias",
            "op_sys" => "All",
            "priority" => "P1",
            "rep_platform" => "All"
        );

        $str_data = json_encode($data);

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$str_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
                array("Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json")); 
        $username = "ashish.sureka@in.abb.com";
        $password = "abbincrc";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch); 

        echo $result
```

Answer (score -1):

Following is the code which worked for me and solved my problem. I am posting it here so that it useful to other. Also I have [written a blog on it](http://ashish-sureka-delhi.blogspot.in/2016/09/invoking-bugzilla-rest-interface-from_16.html).

```
        <?php

        $url = 'http://localhost:8080//bugzilla/xmlrpc.cgi';
        $ch = curl_init();

        $header = array(
            CURLOPT_URL     => $url,
            CURLOPT_POST    => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array( 'Content-Type: text/xml', 'charset=utf-8' )
        );
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $header);

        $bugreport = array(
            'login'       => 'ashish.sureka@in.abb.com',
            'password'    => 'abbincrc',
            'product'     => "TestProduct",
            'component'   => "TestComponent",
            'summary'     => "Bug Title :  A One Line Summary",
            'assigned_to' => "ashish.sureka@in.abb.com",
            'version'     => "unspecified",
            'description' => "Bug Description : A Detailed Problem Description",
            'op_sys'      => "All",
            'platform'    => "All",
            'priority'    => "Normal",
            'severity'    => "Trivial"
        );

        $request = xmlrpc_encode_request("Bug.create", $bugreport); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
        curl_exec($ch)

      ?>
```

Comment: That uses the XMLRPC API, not the REST API, as the question asked.